# How to define clickhouse primary key?

Tags: clickhouse

guys!
I have a table which has some columns below:

- video_id
- type
- uid
- time
- plays

I will regularly insert latest video stats into this table and sum plays by video and hour time.
How to define table's primary key?

I think column type and uid are attributes of table, video_id and time should be the primary key.
I want to know, which is better to define table primary key? video_id and time only or with type and uid?

Comment: https://kb.altinity.com/engines/mergetree-table-engine-family/pick-keys/

Comment: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/optimize/sparse-primary-indexes#ordering-key-columns-efficiently

Answer (score 0):

The real question you should ask is "What do my queries look like?" Specifically, which column (or columns) will I be filtering on the most? The column that is most filtered on should be the first column in your primary key, the second column in the primary key should be the second-most queried column, and so on.

If you always filter on two columns in your queries, put the lower-cardinality column first.

ClickHouse docs have a very detailed explanation of why: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/optimize/sparse-primary-indexes